# Preprocessor metaprogramming library for plain C

Tags: c, metaprogramming, preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

Does anybody know a library similar to `boost::preprocessor` (maybe not so advanced) that could be easily used/incorporated in plain C projects?
Of course, the most (all ?) of `boost::preprocessor` is usable when writing in **C** but I would prefer a small library with only basic capabilities that doesn't depend on the monster like boost.

Comment: Why do you really think that BOOST is a monster? It is big for a reason, also, you don't need the whole boost library, just the preprocessor library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use Boost.Preprocessor. Don't think i haven't read your question entirely. I suggest you use Boost.Preprocessor alone, not the whole boost package. In order to do that, you can use a small utility called [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html) which lets you extract the libraries that you need, in your case Boost.Preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

You can always extract components out of boost using [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/tools/bcp/bcp.html), though, to be honest, i haven't tested that with Boost.Preprocessor yet.
I think you will have a hard time to find other implementations that are as portable as boosts.

Answer (score 1):

P99 (http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/) comes to mind.

Quote:

> P99 is a suite of macro and function definitions that ease the programming in modern C, aka > C99. By using new tools from C99 we implement default arguments for functions, scope bound > resource management, transparent allocation and initialization, ...